# How to compare a generic parameter and a type reference?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

In my TypeScript application, I have an abstract base class named `MyBase`, e.g.:

```js
abstract class MyBase {
    public test() {}
}
```

Let's define a type that represents any class derived from `MyBase`, in *some way* that references the prototype at runtime:

```js
type PluginType = typeof MyBase;
```

Now, in certain parts of the program, modules provide such subclasses and return references to them as values of type `PluginType`. I can use this information to instantiate the subclass, using a method in my framework with the following signature:

```js
function createPlugin(type: PluginType): MyBase
```

Note that any production code in the application that calls this method must not know the subclasses. It is sufficient for it to somehow get the type reference, and then handle the resulting object as if it were of type `MyBase`.

In the unit tests for the application, I am trying to create some helper class that simplifies testing of these subclasses. The helper class should have an interface similar to this:

```js
class TestHelper<T extends MyBase> {
    public constructor(
        private readonly pluginName: string,
        private readonly pluginType: PluginType
        ) {
        // how to compare pluginType and T?
    }

    public createInstance(): T {
        return createPlugin(this.pluginType) as T;
    }
}
```

In the above constructor, I need to check that `pluginType` and `T` actually refer to the same type (or else throw an error).

To illustrate what I mean, in C#, I'd simply write something like

```cs
if (pluginType != typeof(T))
{
    throw ...
}
```

I understand that in TypeScript, and in contrast to C#, generic parameters are lost during compilation. Still, I doubt I really have to specify the very same information (a specific subclass of `MyBase`) twice, redundantly (ugh), without *any* way to compare whether the two values are the same. I am convinced there must be some clever way using typeguards and complex generic type definitions to still get this comparison done ...

**How do I do that in TypeScript?**

If I do not ensure those types are the same, `createInstance` might create an instance of one class that is not actually compatible with type `T`, thus deceiving the type-safety provided by the generic interface. This can be observed on [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRj9Yw).

Comment: @jcalz: Sorry, it's the `Type` type from Angular: https://angular.io/api/core/Type Every time I rediscover that `Type` type does not come from the deepest core of the TypeScript language, but from a 3rd party library, I'm surprised anew.

Comment: @jcalz: I don't think it should be tagged with Angular, should it? After all, the question has nothing to do with Angular. I happen to be using the `Type` definition from the Angular library, because there doesn't seem to be a pre-defined definition like that among the common definitions that come with the TypeScript language, but if you look at the definition on https://angular.io/api/core/Type , you'll see `Type` is not really specific to Angular in any way, it's a simple convenience type def.

Comment: @jcalz: I am not a big fan of minimal reproducible examples (MRE) that can be directly run, as readers then tend to fixate on the specifics of the MRE implementation provided rather than answering the underlying question. Case in point: Our discussion about the definition of the `Type` type and the library it originates from, both of which are actually quite marginal to the question topic. With that said, I see your point about the inconvenience of experimenting with lines from the question if they require additional libraries, so I have picked another way of referring to a TS class.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQJeGN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: Well, that ensures `pluginType` is compatible with `MyBase` - but we already knew that; if it is not, the compiler will complain that `pluginType` does not match `typeof MyBase`. At the same time, `pluginType` might well be compatible with `MyBase`, but not with the particular `MyBase`-subtype `T`, in which case the cast in line 23 would be a dangerous miscast.

Comment:  We didn’t “already know that” given that my example showed a case where you can cause the error to be thrown: a value can be of type `typeof MyBase` without being related to the `MyBase` declaration. TS types are structural, not nominal.  I guess you care more about checking the specific subtype `T`, so this might be a moot point. Still, it’s important to understand the implications of a structural type system, if we’re going to be on the same page.

Comment: (continued, see prev) It seems you already understand that TS's type system is erased when compiled to JS, so your `TestHelper` will look like `class TestHelper { constructor(pluginName, pluginType) {this.pluginName = pluginName; this.pluginType = pluginType} createInstance() { return createPlugin(this.pluginType); }}`. No `T` to be found. If you want something to compare to, you'll have to pass it in *as a value*. I'm not sure why you don't do [this](//tsplay.dev/NdadQm); presumably you want to guard against passing in "the wrong" subtype, but I'd love to see an example. Could you show that?

Comment: (continued once more, last one I promise).  TypeScript is mostly just a static type system for JavaScript, and you can't do anything with TypeScript at runtime that isn't just JavaScript.  (TypeScript does not emit type system metadata to JavaScript.) So... how would you write what you're trying to accomplish with pure JavaScript?  If you can describe such an approach, then maybe we can help give the proper typings for it.   Anyway, I'll disengage now unless I see a [mre] that demonstrates your issue in a way that I can make progress with (and if you don't want it to be runnable then ‍♂️)

Comment: @jcalz: I have added a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRj9Yw) that illustrates the issue. "how would you write what you're trying to accomplish with pure JavaScript?" is a moot point, as JavaScript obviously wouldn't have any generic type parameter that the created instance needs to correspond with. "I'm not sure why you don't do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NdadQm)" - in that case, your "runtime type reference" type generically includes the concrete plugin type, so the type argument for the `TestHelper` ctor can be inferred. Unfortunately, that is something I cannot do due to ...

Comment: ... constraints on said "runtime type reference" type external to the MRE, elsewhere in the application.

Comment: If it can't be done in JavaScript without TypeScript, then it can't be done in TypeScript either.  So I guess the answer here is "this is impossible, sorry".  Assuming you wanted to make it actually possible, you'd start designing your own runtime representation of this information, like maybe a mapping from strings to constructors (e.g., `const ctors = {plugin1: Plugin1, plugin2: Plugin2, ⋯}`) and then call something like `new TestHelper("plugin1", 'p1', Plugin1)` in place of `new TestHelper<Plugin1>('p1', Plugin1)`.  If you did that, we could make TS type check it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: ... I'd be happy to write up an answer saying that what you want is impossible in pure TypeScript (there are undoubtedly build plugins that will generate runtime type info from TS types, but that's out of scope for the question as asked) and that you'll need to either give up or start writing your own runtime type metadata.  Anyway I think I'm repeating myself here so I'll disengage now, unless you'd like to see such an answer. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz: "If it can't be done in JavaScript without TypeScript, then it can't be done in TypeScript either." - I don't think that is accurate as a general statement. Take, for example, this: I want a variable `x` that will accept only string values. Can it be done in TypeScript? Sure, `let x: string;`. But can it be done in JavaScript without TypeScript? No way. And as I said, what I'm asking for here is not so much a problem that *cannot be solved* in plain JS, it's more a problem that doesn't come up in the first place in JS.